# How to solve TypeError: queue.enqueue is not a function"?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to use JavaScript code exactly as the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/extensions/publishers/get-started#lifecycle-events) states, but I'm having trouble especially with the line of code where I have added the ERROR:

```
import { tasks } from "firebase-functions/v1";

import { getDatabase } from "firebase-admin/database";
import { getExtensions } from "firebase-admin/extensions";
import { getFunctions } from "firebase-admin/functions";

export const backfilldata = tasks.taskQueue().onDispatch(async () => {
  const batch = await getDatabase()
    .ref(process.env.MESSAGE_PATH)
    .parent.parent.orderByChild("upper")
    .limitToFirst(20)
    .get();

  const promises = [];
  for (const key in batch.val()) {
    const msg = batch.child(key);
    if (msg.hasChild("original") && !msg.hasChild("upper")) {
      const upper = msg.child("original").val().toUpperCase();
      promises.push(msg.child("upper").ref.set(upper));
    }
  }
  await Promise.all(promises);

  if (promises.length > 0) {
    const queue = getFunctions().taskQueue(
      "backfilldata",
      process.env.EXT_INSTANCE_ID
    );
    return queue.enqueue({}); //######### ERROR #########
  } else {
    return getExtensions()
      .runtime()
      .setProcessingState("PROCESSING_COMPLETE", "Backfill complete.");
  }
});
```

> Exception from a finished function: TypeError: queue.enqueue is not a function

I've seen that `queue` is an object of type [TaskQueueBuilder](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/firebase-functions.tasks.taskqueuebuilder), but this class doesn't even have such a function. How to solve this problem?

Comment: Make sure you are using Gen2 API

Comment: @BadPiggie I'm using v1. How to solve the issue in this case?